# OpenCV findcontour rectangle creation error

Tags: python, opencv

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
leng = int(h*.9)
pt1 = int(y + h // 2 - leng // 2)
pt2 = int(x + w // 2 - leng // 2)
roi = im_th[pt1-int(leng*0.6) : pt1+ int(leng*1.2) , pt2: pt2+leng]
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\kumar\\Desktop\\final year\\test_image\\"+str(idx)+".jpg",roi)
cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,0),3)
roi = roi/255
# Resize the image
roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
roi=roi*255
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\kumar\\Desktop\\final year\\test_image\\after_resize_"+str(idx)+".jpg",roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

while using this block of code to get cropped alphabets out of the image letters such as m and u are creating an error.

[image: u comes out like this]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the photo you are seeing is a cropped image of a small u and as you can see that it cropped it more than requires . so what should i do

Comment: could you tell us the exact problem are you facing?? are you not able to crop 'u' the post some images with 'u' and you are not able to crop it properly.

Comment: my problem was resolved thank you or the help.